# Background image tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get this photo to appear in the background of my window. Its just showing the text at the bottom of the screen and there is no image. Please help.

edit: for some reason my code isn't being formatted

```
import tkinter as ttk
from datetime import datetime

root = ttk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

# -------------get date information---------- #

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%m/%y")

# ------------build window ------------------#
background_image = ttk.PhotoImage("D:\\Programing\\BG_sky1.png")
backgrond_label = ttk.Label(root, image=background_image)
backgrond_label.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

w = ttk.Label(root, text=dt_string)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter doesn't directly support .PNG images.  You'd need to use the PIL/Pillow library to load such a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open png pictures with the PIL module, so this should work:

```
import tkinter as ttk
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = ttk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

# -------------get date information---------- #

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%m/%y")

# ------------build window ------------------#

picture = Image.open("D:\\Programing\\BG_sky1.png")
background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=picture)

backgrond_label = ttk.Label(root, image=background_image)
backgrond_label.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

w = ttk.Label(root, text=dt_string)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Tkinter 8.5 does not support PNG images however if you do upgrade python/Tkinter to 8.6 then it should support PNG images. You can also do something differently by turning a  PNG image into a JPG